# How to check if a certain method/class/API exists in Xamarin iOS?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin, ios8

In [iOS 6 & 7 Compatibility Tips](http://blog.xamarin.com/ios-6-7-compatibility-tips/) it is recommended to check for a specific API like this

```
public static bool IsiOS7 {
  get { return UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion (7, 0); }
}

if(Util.IsiOS7) {
  //Call iOS 7 API
} else {
  //Call iOS 6.1 or earlier API
}
```

The same should go for iOS 8. Now I read that you should check if a certain method or class exists instead of version checking. Here `RespondsToSelector` comes in. That should be something like this

```
if (RespondsToSelector(new Selector("edgesForExtendedLayout")))
       EdgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdge.None;
```

But how would one check if a whole class exists like `UIAlertController`? There is no `NSClassFromString` like in Objective-C. I also saw something like this in Objective-C

```
if ([UIAlertController class]){
    // ...
}
```

Would something like this do the trick?

```
Type type=Type.GetType("UIAlertController");
if(type!=null)
{
    // iOS 8 API
}else{
    // iOS 7 or lower
}
```

How would one do that in C#? Or which other ways exists to check for `UIAlertController`, `UISearchController`, ... and so on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do this:

```cs
using MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime;
bool hasUIAlertController = Class.GetHandle ("UIAlertController") != IntPtr.Zero;
if (hasUIAlertController) {
    // iOS 8
} else {
    // iOS 7 or lower
}
```

Comment: I am using Xamarin.iOS 8.10.1.64 and I get the following error message when I try to build my solution: _Error CS0176: Static member ObjCRuntime.Class.GetHandle(string)' cannot be accessed with an instance reference, qualify it with a type name instead (CS0176)_